# Read entire text file into a Prolog variable

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, dcg

I am having the hardest time figuring this out, even though it is one of the simplest things to do in other languages: Is there a simple way to read the entire contents of a text file into a Prolog variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply state with a DCG what you want to describe, and use library(pio) to parse from a file:

```
:- use_module(library(pio)).

all([])     --> [].
all([L|Ls]) --> [L], all(Ls).
```

Example:

```
?- once(phrase_from_file(all(Ls), 'all.pl')).
Ls = [10, 58, 45, 32, 117, 115, 101, 95, 109|...].
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick for me. I had seen discussions of using DCG's for arbitrary input, but could not make the connection to how this could be used to read in an arbitrary file.

Comment: @sdesciencelover: The big advantage of `library(pio)` will only show, if you do the processing already with the nonterminal. `phrase_from_file/2` does not read the entire file content in one fell swoop but does some internal buffering: In this manner files of abiritrary size can be processed in constant space.

Comment: why once/1? Ideally, SWI should detect determinism. Consider to use call_semidet/1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939794/stack-overflow-in-prolog-dcg-grammar-rule-how-to-handle-large-lists-efficiently/12942551#12942551

Answer (score 3):

in [library(readutil)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.24%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/readutil.html%27%29%29) there are some built ins: see [read_file_to_codes](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_file_to_codes/3) or [read_file_to_terms](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_file_to_terms/3)