# Stack overflow in Prolog DCG grammar rule: how to handle large lists efficiently or lazily

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, dcg

I'm parsing a fairly simple file format consisting of a series of lines, each line having some space separated fields, that looks like this:

```
l 0x9823 1
s 0x1111 3
l 0x1111 12
⋮
```

I'm using SWI-Prolog. This is the DCG I have so far:

```prolog
:- consult(library(pure_input)).

load_trace(Filename, Traces) :-
    phrase_from_file(trace_file_phrase(Traces), Filename).

trace_file_phrase([]) --> [].
trace_file_phrase([T|Ts]) --> trace_phrase(T), trace_file_phrase(Ts).

trace_phrase(access(Type, Address, SinceLast)) -->
    access_type(Type), space,
    address(Address),  space,
    nat(SinceLast),    newline.

access_type(load)  --> "l".
access_type(store) --> "s".

address(Number) --> "0x", hexnum(Number).

hexdigit(N)  --> digit(N).
hexdigit(10) --> "a". hexdigit(11) --> "b". hexdigit(12) --> "c".
hexdigit(13) --> "d". hexdigit(14) --> "e". hexdigit(15) --> "f".
hexnum(N) --> hexdigit(D), hexnum(D, N).
hexnum(N, N) --> [].
hexnum(A, N) --> hexdigit(D), { A1 is A*16 + D }, hexnum(A1, N).

newline --> "\n".
space --> " ".

%% the following two productions are courtesy of Lars Mans at
%% https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279822/parsing-numbers-with-multiple-digits-in-prolog
digit(0) --> "0". digit(1) --> "1". digit(2) --> "2".
digit(3) --> "3". digit(4) --> "4". digit(5) --> "5".
digit(6) --> "6". digit(7) --> "7". digit(8) --> "8".
digit(9) --> "9".

nat(N)   --> digit(D), nat(D,N).
nat(N,N) --> [].
nat(A,N) --> digit(D), { A1 is A*10 + D }, nat(A1, N).
```

As mentioned in the comment, I cribbed the number handling from [Parsing numbers with multiple digits in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279822/parsing-numbers-with-multiple-digits-in-prolog).

The problem I'm running into is some of these files are large, like, on the order of 5-10 MB. The default stack in SWI-Prolog is insufficient for this, and parsing these files is taking substantial time, on the order of 5-15 seconds. I have several questions about this situation:

1. Where is the efficiency problem in this code? I think it's either in `trace_file_phrase//1` or `nat//1` but these are just hunches.
2. If the problem is lists, is there a better way to handle lists with DCGs than this?
3. How does one, in general, diagnose and treat performance problems with DCGs such as this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As a general remark you will find more on SO about it under the name [`library(pio)`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D%20%22library%28pio%29%22). Also the way to use it cleanly is rather:

```
:- use_module(library(pio)).
```

Your example is way too complex, so I will only consider a slightly simpler case, a newline separated list of numbers:

```
nats([]) --> [].
nats([N|Ns]) --> nat(N), newline, nats(Ns).
```

So, how can you test this effectively? (That's your Question 3) The basic point of `library(pio)` is that you can use regular DCGs for file processing. But for testing in the small you can still use the simple `phrase/2`. So I do:

```
?- phrase(nats(Ns),"1\n").
   Ns = [1]
;  false.
```

Did you see the `;` prompt? That means: Prolog was not able to decide whether or not further answers might be computed - so it leaves one or more choice-points open. **And that only for a single digit** You can imagine how things will pile up.

Let's dig deeper:

```
?- phrase(digit(D),"1").
   D = 1
;  false.
```

Again the evil `; false`! In order to make this work, everything would have to be determinate. There are three ways to this:

### Use cuts (and lose your soul)

I wish you luck - the best seems to be just after the repeating element:

```
trace_file_phrase([]) --> [].
trace_file_phrase([T|Ts]) -->
   trace_phrase(T),
   !, % ugly, but...
   trace_file_phrase(Ts).
```

(This should answer Question 1)

But, hold on a minute! What is so bad about this `!`? As long, as there is *exactly* one answer to `trace_phrase//1` things are perfect. It is only, if there are more answers (or actually solutions), that the cut might remove precious answers. How do you know, if there are more solutions? Well, you don't.  And you won't see them as they have been cut away already.

### `call_semidet/1`

Here is a way to ensure that this does not happen. This works only for side-effect free goals that can be called twice without any effect:

```
call_semidet(Goal) :-
   (  call_nth(Goal, 2)
   -> throw(error(mode_error(semidet,Goal),_))
   ;  once(Goal)
   ).
```

This uses [`call_nth/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364634/count-the-number-of-call-of-a-clause-prolog/11400256#11400256), as defined in another post. (As an optimization, the implementation could avoid calling `Goal` twice when there is no choice-point open...) Just to make clear, how it works:

```
?- phrase(nat(N),"1234").
   N = 1234
;  false.
?- call_semidet(phrase(nat(N),"1234")).
   N = 1234.
?- call_semidet((X=1;X=2)).
   error(mode_error(semidet, (2=1;2=2)), _).
```

So it makes your little grammar effectively determinate! There is thus no need to reformulate anything!

What is lacking now is some integration of this into the grammar. You can do this very low-level, or rather cleanly using [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl).

```
phrase_semidet(NT) -->
   call(S0^S^call_semidet(phrase(NT,S0,S))).
```

Note that in this very particular case we do not use the `\` for renaming.

```
trace_file_phrase([]) --> [].
trace_file_phrase([T|Ts]) -->
   phrase_semidet(trace_phrase(T)),
   trace_file_phrase(Ts).
```

### Exploit indexing

Finally, a very laborious but clean way would be to rewrite everything to profit better from indexing (and maybe help to improve indexing in general...) But this is a long road. Just to start with:

```
digit(D) --> [C],
   {c_digit(C,D)}.

c_digit(0'0,0).
c_digit(0'1,1).
c_digit(0'2,2).
c_digit(0'3,3).
c_digit(0'4,4).
c_digit(0'5,5).
c_digit(0'6,6).
c_digit(0'7,7).
c_digit(0'8,8).
c_digit(0'9,9).
```

This gives you now:

```
?- phrase(digit(D),"1").
   D = 1.
```

But you have another source of nondeterminism which is rather due to the way you define the grammar. In `nat//2` you see it:

```
nat(N,N) --> [].
nat(A,N) --> digit(D), ... .
```

The first rule always applies, that is, `"1234\n"` will be parsed as `"1"` `"12"` `"123"` `"1234"` only the following `newline//0` realizes that it would suffice go for the last — and then stick to it.

You can rewrite things for that, but then, the code is no longer the pure little spec you liked, isn't it? Well, maybe things might improve in the future.

E.g. indexing is much better in SWI than it used to be, maybe also things evolve here too....

The intention of `library(pio)` was to get this process started. Compare this to Haskell — we are far away from `interact` efficiency-wise! But there is no **inherent** cost:

```
... --> [] | [_], ... .

?- phrase_from_file((...,"searchstring",...),fichier).
```

is just as efficient as grep — space-wise. That is, it runs in constant space. So hopefully more code will run better in the future.

Edit: BTW, `library(pio)` did already have an impact efficiency-wise: GC phases were improved significantly, very much in the same manner as Wadler's Fixing some space leak – paper a quarter century ago. Things evolve ...

Edit almost 10 years later: [a related](https://github.com/mthom/scryer-prolog/discussions/1573#discussioncomment-3403982) answer.

Comment: I thought `nat/2` looked a little obtuse. Can you expand a little on what I need to do to fix the problem there? I'm less worried about that rule becoming obtuse since it can be sequestered in a module elsewhere and not interfere with my "pure little spec"--if the infection won't spread.

Comment: @DanielLyons: Could you share the actual numbers? Then this would be also useful for other people.

Comment: @DanielLyons: You wrote in your question 5-10MB took 5-15s and much more than default space. How is the situation now?

Comment: @DanielLyons: you never answered this question, or did you?

Comment: No, I didn't. I will try to find some time during my upcoming vacation to perform meaningful benchmarks. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I've verified the stackoverflow on a 2Mb file. Then I rewrote the grammar using library(dcg/basics), and now is working.

```
:- [library(dcg/basics)].

load_trace_0(Filename, Ls) :-
    phrase_from_file(lines(Ls), Filename).

lines([s(H,I)|R]) -->
    "s 0x", xinteger(H), " ",
    integer(I), blanks,
    !, lines(R).
lines([l(H,I)|R]) -->
    "l 0x", xinteger(H), " ",
    integer(I), blanks,
    !, lines(R).
lines([]) --> [].
```

But then I tried to put the cut on your grammar, and is working as well. So the answer from @gusbro (+1) solves your problem.

Comment: Is `dcg/basics` contributing `integer/3` and `xinteger/3` in your code? I haven't heard about this before.

Comment: yes, it's handy. I routinely use it to parse mySQL backup files of about 10 MB

Comment: Thanks for this, it has helped tremendously. I wish I could split accepting the answer three ways!

Answer (score 4):

About the efficiency problem:

If your input is usually well formed, then I think you should swap the clauses of `nat/4` and `hexnum/4`, so they would read:

```
nat(A,N) --> digit(D), { A1 is A*10 + D }, nat(A1, N).
nat(N,N) --> [].

hexnum(A, N) --> hexdigit(D), { A1 is A*16 + D }, hexnum(A1, N).
hexnum(N, N) --> [].
```

because you only want to stop parsing a number when there are no more digits to consume.

If used wisely, the cut (`!`) can help you performance-wise and also regarding the stack overflow because it prunes the prolog evaluation tree. For example, you may commit (`!`) at the end of `trace_file_phrase/3` (that is, after the `newline`) because you don't need to reparse that part of the input again to find other solutions.

Comment: I guess I'm just not seeing where I should place a cut to improve things.

Comment: @DanielLyons: for example, you can commit (`!`) at the end of `trace_file_phrase/3` (that is, after the newline) because you don't need to reparse that part of the input again to find other solutions.

Comment: This will only work if you add a cut after `digit//1`, otherwise it is less efficient, because a choice-point is left for each recursion.

Comment: @false: I already said he should use cuts, and even if he doesn't use cuts we should measure time to see which is more efficient.

Comment: @gusbro: Without a cut after `digit//1` your definition will use one choice-point for each digit. That is forbidding. Daniel Lyons original definition was much better in this respect. Only one superficial choice-point for each number.

Comment: Thanks for this, using the cut after the newline alone turned out to solve the basic problem. If I could I'd accept all three answers!