# Rewriting tail recursion prolog code into simple recursion

Tags: recursion, prolog, tail-recursion

I'm quite new in prolog and I want to practice rewriting a tail-recursion code into a simple recursion to understand better the process, but I did not succeed in it. If anybody can help with it I would really appreciate it.

---

**Note**: Converting tail-recursive ([tail-call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)) code to non tail-recursive code is not a wise thing to normally do in Prolog. This question is only for academic purposes of learning.

---

The code:

```
some_predicate(T,1,3,0,D),
%the tail has elements with ID and Numbers like [(1,3),(2,5),(4,3)])
%in the D I count steps if different conditions are fulfilled
%I would like to write something like: some_predicate(T,1,3,D) without the Acc

some_predicate(_, _, 1, D, D):-!.
some_predicate([], _, _, D, D):-!.
some_predicate([(UP,_)|_], ID, H, D, D):-
    UP >= ID + H,
    !.
some_predicate([(UP,UH)|T], _, H, D, RetD):-
    H > UH,
    TH is H - 1,
    TD is D + 1,
    some_predicate(T, UP, TH, TD, RetD),
    !.
some_predicate([(UP,UH)|T], _, _,D, RetD):-
    TD is D + 1,
    some_predicate(T, UP, UH, TD, RetD),
    !.
```

My attempt

```
some_predicate(_, _, 1,0):-!.
some_predicate([], _, _,0):-!.
some_predicate([(UP,_)|_], ID, H, 0):-
    UP >= ID + H,
    !.
some_predicate([(UP,UH)|Er], _, H, D):-
    H > UH,
    some_predicate(Er, UP, TH, TD),
    H is TH - 1,
    D is TD + 1,
    !.
some_predicate([(UP,UH)|Er], _, _,D):-
    some_predicate(Er, UP, UH, TD),
     D is TD + 1,
     !.
```

Comment: But why would you want to sacrifice the possibility of having the compiler optimize the recursion into a loop?

Comment: My university task is to write a code snippet in two different ways, a tail-rec and a simple recursion and mark the differences. I prefer the tail-recursion too and as you can see I managed to solve the problem in that way, but I have to do it with non-tailrec  too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out if Prolog performs Tail Call Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433488/how-to-find-out-if-prolog-performs-tail-call-optimization)

Comment: I am sorry to give this a down-vote but I really consider the title damaging. For someone new to Prolog they might get the impression from the title that tail recursion is a bad thing. It is the opposite, it is a very good thing. I do understand what you are trying to accomplish which is why the link in the previous comment should be of use to you.

Comment: I understand, thank you for the note section editing. To be honest the linked question didn't really helped me, but I'm still trying to rewrite it. If I can solve it, I will answer my question later, but thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A comment in the question says that you would like to rewrite the code without an accumulator, but *it doesn't use an accumulator*. The general schema for predicates using a list accumulator would be something like this:

```
foo(X, Ys) :-
    foo(X, [], Ys).

foo(X, Acc, Acc) :-
    bar(X).
foo(X, Acc, Ys) :-
    baz(X, Y, Z),
    foo(Z, [Y | Acc], Ys).
```

The recursive call involving the list accumulator gets a **bigger** list than the accumulator was before. You *add* something to the accumulator before you pass it to the recursive call.

Your program instead uses the common pattern of "list iteration" (comments with a better name are welcome) in Prolog which does the opposite of recursion using an accumulator:

```
foo([], Y) :-
    bar(Y).
foo([X | Xs], Y) :-
    baz(X),
    foo(Xs, Y).
```

*(This uses similar names to the predicate before, but I'm not saying that they are equivalent.)*

The list constructor `[_ | _]` is in the *head* of the clause, not in a recursive call. The list in the recursive call is **smaller** than the list in the head. You *remove* something from the list before you pass the tail to the recursive call.

This is therefore not an answer your question, just a hint that you need to start from the right place: Some predicate definition that really does use an accumulator list. The simplest interesting case is probably reversing a list.