# How to check if the value is a number in Prolog manually?

Tags: numbers, prolog

How to check if the given value is a number in Prolog without using built-in predicates like `number`?

Let's say I have a list `[a, 1, 2, 3]`. I need a way to check if every element within this list is a number. The only part of the problem that bothers me is how to do the check itself without using the `number` predicate.

The reason why I'm trying to figure this out is that I've got a college assignment where it's specifically said not to use any of the built-in predicates.

Comment: What's the complete story? Why not use the built-in? Is the value given as atom or a string?

Comment: for a digital [Presocratic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presocratics/), **all** is number

Comment: @Little Bobby Tables: The value is given as an atom.

Comment: @Luka: You mean, the list is `[a, '1', '2', '3']`?

Comment: @False: No, I mean exactly `[a, 1, 2, 3]` (without quotes).

Comment: What do you then mean by "The value is given as an atom"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need some built-in predicate to solve this problem - unless you enumerate all numbers explicitly (which is not practical since there are infinitely many of them).

## 1

The most straight-forward would be:

```
maplist(number, L).
```

Or, recursively

```
allnumbers([]).
allnumbers([N|Ns]) :-
   number(N),
   allnumbers(Ns).
```

## 2

In a comment you say that "the value is given as an atom". That could mean that you get either [a, '1', '2'] or '[a, 1, 2]`. I assume the first. Here again, you need a built-in predicate to analyze the name. Relying on ISO-Prolog's errors we write:

```
numberatom(Atom) :-
   atom_chars(Atom, Chs),
    catch(number_chars(_, Chs), error(syntax_error(_),_), false).
```

Use `numberatom/1` in place of `number/1`, So write a recurse rule or use `maplist/2`

## 3

You might want to write a grammar instead of the `catch...` goal. There have been many such definitions recently, you may look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12939794/772868).

## 4

If the entire "value" is given as an atom, you will need again `atom_chars/2`or you might want some implementation specific solution like `atom_to_term/3` and then apply one of the solutions above.